# VBA Word: Insert text before found text in word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

What I want to do is something simple (maybe). I have written a find method to loop around the document. I have find value - ']' and insert value - '[('. In between those two there can be any kind of number most likely from 1 - 100.

My current code is this:

```
Sub FindBracket()
Dim FindValue As String
Dim ReplaceValue As String
Dim oRange As Range

Set oRange = ActiveDocument.Range
FindValue = "]"
InsertValue = "(["

With oRange.Find
    .Text = FindValue
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    
    Do While .Execute = True
        If .Found Then
            oRange.InsertBefore (InsertValue)
        End If
        oRange.Start = oRange.End
        oRange.End = ActiveDocument.Range.End
    Loop
End With
End Sub
```

The find method works good, but I need to modify .InsertBefore method.

***Example***
I would need to transform **' Dummy text 1] '** to this **' Dummy text [(1] '** but from the code I get **' Dummy text 1[(] '**, I cannot seem to figure out how to do that, and I have only previous experience with Excel VBA only.

Would appreciate any help on this, than you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub FindBracket()
    Dim FindValue As String
    Dim ReplaceValue As String
    Dim oRange As Range

    Set oRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    FindValue = "[0-9]@\]"
    InsertValue = "[(^&"    ' ^& - found number
    
    With oRange.Find
        .Text = FindValue
        .Replacement.Text = InsertValue
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True      ' enabled regular expressions
        
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub

Before:
Dummy text 1234]
Dummy text 4321]
Dummy text 0]
Dummy text 1]

After:
Dummy text [(1234]
Dummy text [(4321]
Dummy text [(0]
Dummy text [(1]
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much, this solution also works!

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
Sub FindBracket()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Text = "[0-9]@\]"
  .Replacement.Text = "[(^&"
  .Forward = True
  .Format = False
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .MatchWildcards = True
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Indeed, you don't even need a macro - it could all be done through the GUI using a *wildcard* Find/Replace with the same F/R expressions.